# Should interfaces such as NonCopyable and NonMovable provide virtual destructors?

Tags: c++

Should interfaces such as NonCopyable and NonMovable provide virtual destructors or not, and just declare the destructor protected?

I can't imagine anyone wanting to store objects as NonCopyable/NonMovable and use them in a polymorphic way like this.

Comment: Can you inherit from them protected/private to avoid the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With C++11, you can delete constructors and destructors, rendering many NonCopyable / NonMovable idioms obsolete:

```
YourClass() = delete; /*deletion of default constructor*/
YourClass(const YourClass&) = delete; /*deletion of copy constructor*/
~YourClass() = delete; /*deletion of the destructor of YourClass*/
```

etc. You'll get a compile time failure if any code requires these.

Comment: Is this the preferred way? It might become a bit tedious to do this for every class that requires such features.

Comment: How can you delete destructor?

Comment: Tedious but very clear and very portable. You could wrap it up in a template traits / policy class but take care not to obfuscate.

Comment: @NeilKirk: delete destructor as above. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor. Code requiring a destructor will not compile. (Normally done for unions).

Answer (score 2):

No non copyable base won't require a virtual destructor. But yes the class that extends this non-copyable may required virtual destructor.

If you are using boost, you can inherit from [noncopyable.hpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1%5f41%5f0/boost/noncopyable.hpp)

Comment: It's more of a question what to do when having my own NonCopyable/NonMovable. Should I provide a virtual destructor, I guess not.

Comment: Virtual destructor is useful when you store objects in pointed by pointers of your base class. Here unless you use base (non copyable reference), there is no need. So I don't see a need.

Answer (score 0):

The traits NonCopyable and NonMovable are orthogonal to each other and to polymorphic use.
So why shouldn't someone want to mix-and-match in any combination?

Anyway, the proper way to avoid the issue is declaring those classes destructor protected, and only inherit them private. Neil Kirk is right about that.

Also, since C++11, you can explicitly declare any function you want deleted, which is the preferred way.